# ggplotly how to change tool tip and the text on the right side

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, plotly

```
library("ggplot2")
draw_a_boxplot <- function(data,y,color){
  data$quality <- as.factor(data$quality)
  p <- ggplot(data,aes(data[,I(color)],data[,y]))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(colour=data[,color]))+
    geom_jitter(width = 0.2,aes(colour=data[,color]))+
    xlab(color) +
    ylab(y) +
    ggtitle(paste0("BoxPlot-Jitter-",color,"-",y))
  return(ggplotly(p,tooltip = c("y", "x", "colour")))
}
draw_a_boxplot(wines,"volatile.acidity","quality")
```

This is my code for drawing the boxplot I am able to creat boxplot but I want to change the tool tip text and text on right side.How to make ggpotly to use tooltips of ggplot2

[image: Boxplot]

I am attaching the dataset link  [Dataset](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://s3.amazonaws.com/udacity-hosted-downloads/ud651/wineQualityReds.csv&sa=D&ust=1486117062730000&usg=AFQjCNG_DzZUXEbr2h8P4yOulTjOD_PLRQ)

Comment: You want to change how? And instead of a link you could use dput() to add your dataset to your post.

Comment: I would like to add my own names @MLavoie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

You just need to text to your `ggplot` call and then ask it in your `tooltip` argument.

```
draw_a_boxplot <- function(data,y,color){
  data$quality <- as.factor(data$quality)
  p <- ggplot(data,aes(data[,I(color)],data[,y], text = paste("TextYouWant1:", data[,I(color)], "<br>", "TextYouWant2:", data[,y]), "<br>", "TextYouWant3:", data[,color]))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(colour=data[,color]))+
    geom_jitter(width = 0.2,aes(colour=data[,color]))+
    xlab(color) +
    ylab(y) +
    ggtitle(paste0("BoxPlot-Jitter-",color,"-",y))
  return(ggplotly(p,tooltip = c("text")))
}
draw_a_boxplot(wines,"volatile.acidity","quality")
```